# Scheduling R script which generates some graphs and data frames

Tags: r

I would like to schedule my R script which generates some data frames and some graphs.

I would like to schedule the output of the script. So my question is, there are some places where it prints the data frames and some places it generates the graph. How do I make this streamlined and show it in a document or email body which will have the tables and graphs in it? so it can be scheduled.

Comment: how do I make it schedule then?

Comment: ohhh!! sorry I copied the wrong link :/
here:
http://www.bnosac.be/index.php/blog/50-taskscheduler-r-package-to-schedule-r-scripts-with-the-windows-task-manager-2

hope this helps

Comment: okay, thank you, but how do I invoke rmarkdown with scheduler? bit confused

Comment: I apologize about this, the markdown comment was posted by mistake (I copied the wrong link), which is why I removed it now.
however when I read your question , I remembered that I read about an R-Package that helps with such stuff (`taskscheduleR`), and that's what the link is about.